# How to use a directive outside of a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created a **popover** module, which exports two **components** and three **directives**. I am not able to use the directives outside of the main component. If I do I get an editor error of:

> No provider for MatPopoverComponent

and a browser error of:

> ERROR Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [MatPopoverComponent]

Is there any way for me to use the directives outside of the component?

This current usage works:

```html
<mat-popover>
  <mat-popover-content>Some Content</mat-popover-content>
  <button toggle-popover>Click Me</button>
</mat-popover>
```

However, I would like to use it like this:

```html
<mat-popover>
  <mat-popover-content>Some Content</mat-popover-content>
</mat-popover>

<button toggle-popover>Click Me</button>
```

This is one of the directives (All three are the same except for the body of the click event).

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[toggle-popover]'
})
export class TogglePopoverDirective {

  public constructor(private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, @Host() private popover: MatPopoverComponent) { }

  @HostListener('click')
  public onClick() {
    this.popover.toggle(this.el)
  }
}
```

This is the main component using a directive outside of this gives me the errors above.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-popover',
  templateUrl: './popover.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popover.component.scss']
})
export class MatPopoverComponent {

  @ContentChild(MatPopoverContentComponent)
  public content: MatPopoverContentComponent

  public toggle(el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
    this.content.elementRef = el
    this.content.togglePopover()
  }

  public open(el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
    this.content.elementRef = el
    this.content.openPopover()
  }

  public close() {
    this.content.closePopover()
  }
}
```

This is the popover module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [MatPopoverComponent],
  declarations: [
    MatPopoverComponent,
    MatPopoverContentComponent,
    OpenPopoverDirective,
    ClosePopoverDirective,
    TogglePopoverDirective
  ],
  exports: [
    MatPopoverComponent,
    MatPopoverContentComponent,
    OpenPopoverDirective,
    ClosePopoverDirective,
    TogglePopoverDirective
  ]
})
export class MatPopoverModule { }
```

Comment: Where's the module definition?

Comment: @EliasSoares Which module? The Popover module or the module using the popover?

Comment: The Popover module

Comment: Okay I added it

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the @Host decorator. I'm not sure you can use it this way. Let me search a little bit and I try to answer you

Comment: @EliasSoares Hmm, Looks like you are correct, removing that injector removes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create what I was looking for by removing the `@Host()` decorator, and provide a template reference to the directive. It now looks like this:

```
<mat-popover #myPopover>
  <mat-popover-content>Some Content</mat-popover-content>
</mat-popover>

<button [toggle-popover]="myPopover">Click Me</button>
```

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[toggle-popover]'
})
export class TogglePopoverDirective {

  @Input('toggle-popover')
  public popover: MatPopoverComponent

  public constructor(private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) { }

  @HostListener('click')
  public onClick() {
    this.popover.toggle(this.el)
  }
}
```